# ActiveMQ alerting old messages

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, monitoring, messaging, amq

I am using ActiveMQ and want to generate alerts for messages which are sitting int the queue for very long time. I looked at "Advisory Message" feature but it has no such provision. It is very important for me to use a solution which does not add too much overhead on AMQ.

Note:This requirement is very different from alerts when message moves to DLQ after expiry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only means of reviewing what is in a Queue really is to browse it and the broker will place limitations on how far into the contents of the queue you can browse.

A message broker is not a database and you should not try to treat as such.  If you have concerns about things remaining on a queue for to long then explicit expiration is your most effective tool.

You can build you own tooling to track the advisories around message enqueue and dequeue but you'd just end up needing to persist that information to make it effective so going back and reevaluating why you need to do this and what might be a better choice of architecture might be appropriate.

If you insist on want to audit the contents of the Queues then you'd want to look at configuration for max browse page size to try and let you get further into the Queue on a browse but depending on depth this probably won't get you everything you want.